# Delete Confirmation Message in CommandField?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying get **confirmation** message **while click** on **delete** button in  **GridView**. If I **conform** only the row will be delete in **GridView**.

***.ASPX**

```
<Columns>

    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowDeleteButton="true" />

</Columns>
```

***.ASPX.CS**

```
protected void grdPersTable_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Button buttonCommandField = e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as Button;
        buttonCommandField.Attributes["onClick"] = 
               string.Format("return confirm('Are you want delete ')");
    }
}

protected void grdPersTable_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl0 = (Label)grdPersTable.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblId");
    txtId.Text = lbl0.Text;
    obj.DeleteV(Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text));
    grdPersTable.DataSource = obj.GetTableValues();
    grdPersTable.DataBind();        
    lblMessage.Text = "Deleted successfully !";
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got answer friends

```
<asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="deletebtn" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" 
             Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" />
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

i changed **CommandField** to **TemplateField**

Thanks !

Comment: Are you still able to use the DeleteCommand feature on the DataSource, if that is where you called the delete SQL - if you are using SQL?

Answer (score 2):

Change the rowdatabound event as below.

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ((Button)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0]).OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I used above Code.. I getting error like "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'. "

Comment: use this ((LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0]).OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');";

Answer (score 1):

Just call a javascript function on onclientclick event and ask for confirmation. If it returns true then you can call the server side code to delete.

Below is the code for explanation

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" runat="server" OnClick="lbDelete_Click" OnClientClick="return fnConfirm();"> Delete</asp:LinkButton>
```

And below is the javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fnConfirm() {
    if (confirm("The item will be deleted. Are you sure want to continue?") == true)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
</script>
```

You can check the detailed article with source code in the below link

http://www.dotnetpickles.com/2013/03/how-to-show-confirm-message-while.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DELETE" ShowHeader="False">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to Delete?')">
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                                CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's documentation shows an example of how to do this using the ASP DataSource's DeleteCommand parameter:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.deletecommand?view=netframework-4.8

It uses the DataSource class's "OnDeleting" parameter and event.