# Trying to create confirmation dialog deleting a row from a GridView using CommandField, will delete regardless of choice

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have an asp:GridView containing a CommandField.

When I click on the delete image, OnRowDeleting will be called in the code behind.

I want to add a confirm dialog, using jquery.

Trying this:

```
$('input[alt="Ta bort"]').click(function(e)
{
   var target = e.which;

   var tr = $(target).closest('tr');
   var td = tr.find("td:first");

   if (!confirm("Do you want to remove the line where the first cell reads" + td.text() + "?"))
   {
      return false;
   }
});
```

I have no idea how the text "Ta bort" actually comes into that alt attribute, its "remove" in my language, must be automatically generated, because nothing in my aspx code reads "Ta bort". I find no other way of writing a selector easily beside using that alt text.

The confirm appears, but the event will never get cancelled. Meaning that even if I choose "no", the line is removed.

Why?

I also tried `e.preventDefault();`

I do not want to create a TemplateField instead of CommandField as suggested at [Delete Confirmation Message in CommandField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634454/delete-confirmation-message-in-commandfield)

Answer (score 0):

you can use like below

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                        CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record');"></asp:LinkButton>
```

refer this [reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317694/how-to-add-delete-confirmation-prompt-for-command-field-in-detail-view)